# MoveIt! Rviz Plugin - No interactive markers visible/available

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, interactive-markers, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all,

I created a Robot-Config via MoveIt! Setup Assistant. The Robot is a simple 6 Dof Robot.

When I start it with the Rviz Moveit Plugin the interactive markers are not displayed. (After I click on "Interact"). I suspect the End-Effector is not correctly set by me.

### RVIZ:

[image: image description]

Screenshots of the MoveIt Setup Assistant:

**1.**
[image: image description]

**2.**
[image: image description]

I set for both plannings groups the "KDLKinematicsPlugin" as Solver on default values.
I followed [this tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start) for the pr2-robot.

### My .launch-file:

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find tx60l_final3)/launch/upload_tx60l.launch"/>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom_combined base_footprint 100" />

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
 <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
</node>

<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="true" output="screen"/>

  <include file="$(find tx60l_final3)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="allow_trajectory_execution" value="false"/>
  </include>

<include file="$(find tx60l_final3)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>

</launch>
```

**Edit (no gazebo-part in urdf):** See here the [Terminal-Output](http://pastebin.com/d5X5EBTc).

**Info:** Removing and adding "MotionPlanning" inside Rviz didn't help.

**Edit (working Links):**
Here you can download my [robot-description](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7328348/tx60l_final3.zip.html).
Here you can download my [urdf-folder](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7328322/learning_urdf.zip.html).

**Update:** If I set the "fixed_frame" to a link of the robot itself, interactive markers for joint a4 show up. (See picture below) But I need interactive markers in joint5. If I let "fixed_frame" set on "base_footprint" or "odom_combined" (as it should be, I think) and "plan and execute" for a random query MoveIt! crashes ([output](http://pastebin.com/wxMLn79A))

[image: image description]

**Update:** Now the interactive markers work correctly.
Many Thanks to all supporters.

viovio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57611/moveit!-rviz-plugin---no-interactive-markers-visible/available/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-03-14**:
Please mark an answer as correct, so the question is flagged as "answered".  Glad it's working for you!  Consider looking into http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial, which has several tutorials and templates for controlling your industrial robot through ROS.  We'd love to add support for Staubli to ROS-I !

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-03**:
did you tried to connect that to real robot or the simulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me, it looks like the issue is that your joint_state_publisher is crashing due to a malformed robot URDF.  See the following snippet from your error log:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 3, column 4
[joint_state_publisher-3] process has died
```

I was able to reproduce the error using the `tx60l.urdf` supplied in your links.  The issue here is with the `<gazebo>` section in your URDF.  The joint_state_publisher uses a python minidom XML parser, which is more picky about XML syntax than the TinyXML C++ parser used in much of the rest of ROS (including the check_urdf test you ran earlier).  Even though the TinyXML parser can handle your URDF, the minidom parser requires a little bit more help...

To fix the error, you have two options:

1. remove the `<gazebo>` section from your URDF
2. or update the URDF to a "more correct" format:
3. move the `<gazebo>` section *inside* the `<robot>` section
4. add `xmlns` qualifiers to the robot tag as shown:

---

```
<robot name="TX60L">
       xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
       xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface">
  <gazebo>
    ...
  </gazebo>
  <link name="base_link">
    ...
</robot>
```

Using these changes, I was able to get the joint_state_publisher to run without errors.  I expect this will also fix the issue you were having with missing interactive markers.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-14**:
Thx for your answer. I updated the links, so it must work now. My urdf file seems to be fine according to check_urdf.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-14**:
In the meantime I also noticed this. I removed it and the joint_state_publisher starts correctly. But this doesn't solve the problem. But I noticed something interesting: When setting the fixed_frame from odom_combined  to a link of the robot itself, interactive markers appear for the a4-link!

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-03-14**:
I think you are seeing the correct behavior.  What are you expecting to see?  For a fixed robot, you shouldn't need to define odom_combined.  It is appropriate to set the fixed_frame in rviz to base_link of your robot.

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-03-14**:
Similarly, at4 is the last link in your robot_arm group.  That's where the markers should be shown.  If you prefer to include the at5 link, then you need to add it to your robot_arm group.  This may require you to use a dummy (fixed) joint for the EE group, if you don't have a true gripper.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-14**:
Thx. I followed your comment and the interactive markers are now on their right spot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried disabling and then re-enabling the MoveIt plugin? I've noticed in the past that if RVIZ starts before MoveIt is really up and running, the markers don't work.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-10**:
Not yet, how can I do that?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-10**:
On each plugin there is a checkbox next to it to enable/disable it.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-10**:
Unfortunately it does not work. I guess you mean the checkbox next to MotionPlanning in Panel "Displays".

**Comment by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on 2013-03-13**:
I confirm that disabling/enabling the MotionPlanning panel does fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone else comes across this issue, you can get more debug info with the following steps:

1. In the Displays panel of RViz, click Add > By topic > select InteractiveMarkers under /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display
2. In my case I see the error "Error getting time of latest transform between /world and world: (error code: 1)" for this interactive marker in the Displays panel.

This helped me debug that my issue is related to the robot being in a namespace. (A quick fix in this case is to manually publish the transform with "rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 /world /{robot_namespace}/world 10")

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oldham](https://answers.ros.org/users/31353/oldham/) on 2017-07-26**:
Your error is similar to mine, but when I try your fix it doesn't work for me.  Could it be a problem simply with having slashes?

**Comment by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) on 2017-07-26**:
what's the error that you see? the frames with/without a slash in the error message that I mentioned have significantly different meaning: '/world' is a global frame and 'world' is a local frame. Probably whatever was publishing it as a local frame (I forget what) should have been doing it as global

**Comment by [oldham](https://answers.ros.org/users/31353/oldham/) on 2017-07-26**:
Ah okay! I was revising a different deprecated MoveIt! tutorial but I found the issue once the global/local difference was made clear.  Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) on 2017-07-26**:
glad to hear that helped