# RViz crashes during MoveIt Quickstart in RViz tutorial (namespace collision?)

Tags: ros2, rviz, moveit-tutorial, moveit2

I am trying to run the MoveIt Quickstart in RViz tutorial. Unfortunately, RViz crashes during the launch. My problem seems similar to [this one](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104509/rviz-is-crashing-in-moveit-2-tutorials) but that is built on a windows system, so it seems a bit different.

My environment

```
ROS Distro: Humble
OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04
Source build: Main
System: Laptop: Razor Blade
        Memory: Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 12
        Graphics: NV136 / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
        Disk: 1 TB
```

I have fairly clean build of Ubuntu 22.04. That said, building Moveit2 was giving me a hard time. I only built successfully with:
MAKEFLAGS="-j4 -l1" colcon build --executor sequential
RViz is built using the source files in the /opt/ros/humble directory (I think that is the default install location while following the Ros2 setup tutorial). The rviz_visual_tools package is built from home/jake/ws_moveit/src and is located in home/jake/ws_moveit/build.

Backtrace

> ws_moveit$ ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py
> [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/jake/.ros/log/2024-03-13-11-07-50-050628-jake-Blade-29447
> [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
> [INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [29448]
> [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process started with pid [29450]
> [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [29452]
> [INFO] [move_group-4]: process started with pid [29454]
> [INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [29456]
> [INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [29458]
> [INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [29460]
> [INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [29462]
> [rviz2-1] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
> [static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1710353270.599045049] [static_transform_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
> [static_transform_publisher-2] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
> [static_transform_publisher-2] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
> [static_transform_publisher-2] from 'world' to 'base_link'
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626137892] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626282510] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bracelet_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626302550] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment end_effector_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626314832] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forearm_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626325727] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment half_arm_1_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626336031] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment half_arm_2_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626346514] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_base_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626357257] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_finger_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626367777] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_finger_tip_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626378339] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_inner_knuckle_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626388758] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_knuckle_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626398671] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_finger_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626408600] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_finger_tip_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626418496] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_inner_knuckle_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626443678] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_knuckle_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626450662] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment shoulder_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626458236] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment spherical_wrist_1_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626465807] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment spherical_wrist_2_link
> [robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1710353270.626474813] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.638806992] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.640367296] [controller_manager]: update rate is 1000 Hz
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.640584825] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.650818834] [controller_manager]: Received robot description file.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.651640178] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652670593] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1710353270.652699997] [mock_generic_system]: Parameter 'fake_sensor_commands' has been deprecated from usage. Use'mock_sensor_commands' instead.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1710353270.652734799] [mock_generic_system]: Parsing of optional initial interface values failed or uses a deprecated format. Add initial values for every state interface in the ros2_control.xacro. For example:
> [ros2_control_node-5] <state_interface name="velocity">
> [ros2_control_node-5] 0.0
> [ros2_control_node-5] </state_interface>
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652751403] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652780335] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652798744] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1710353270.652813936] [mock_generic_system]: Parameter 'fake_sensor_commands' has been deprecated from usage. Use'mock_sensor_commands' instead.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652836302] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652904956] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652926715] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652938272] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652945529] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652953124] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652963177] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652974837] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.652981752] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
> [move_group-4] [INFO] [1710353270.672341286] [move_group.moveit.RDFLoader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0052989 seconds
> [move_group-4] [INFO] [1710353270.672404928] [move_group.moveit.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
> [move_group-4] [INFO] [1710353270.672421428] [move_group.moveit.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.783256464] [controller_manager]: Received robot description file.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1710353270.783301276] [controller_manager]: ResourceManager has already loaded an urdf file. Ignoring attempt to reload a robot description file.
> [move_group-4] [INFO] [1710353270.832842673] [move_group.moveit.kdl_kinematics_plugin]:   Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> [move_group-4] malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.944747493] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.957491361] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1710353270.970609689] [joint_trajectory_controller]:   [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.974082403] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'robotiq_gripper_controller'
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353270.990812563] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353270.990990897] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
> [spawner-6] [INFO] [1710353270.991016624] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.992116534] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353270.992237918] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
> [spawner-7] [INFO] [1710353271.002768400] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Loaded joint_trajectory_controller
> [spawner-6] [INFO] [1710353271.002828010] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.004004066] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.004223576] [joint_trajectory_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.004273761] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.004295607] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.005583050] [joint_trajectory_controller]:   Controller state will be published at 100.00 Hz.
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.007092888] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
> [spawner-8] [INFO] [1710353271.011478647] [spawner_robotiq_gripper_controller]: Loaded robotiq_gripper_controller
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.013969993] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'robotiq_gripper_controller'
> [ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1710353271.014043030] [robotiq_gripper_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20Hz.
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353271.015404363] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
> [spawner-7] [INFO] [1710353271.017632911] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Configured and activated joint_trajectory_controller
> [spawner-8] [INFO] [1710353271.023057065] [spawner_robotiq_gripper_controller]: Configured and activated robotiq_gripper_controller
> [rviz2-1] [WARN] [1710353271.139714520] [rcl.logging_rosout]: Publisher already registered for provided node name. If this is due to multiple nodes with the same name then all logs for that logger name will go out over the existing publisher. As soon as any node with that name is destructed it will unregister the publisher, preventing any further logs for that name from being published on the rosout topic.
> [INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 29458]
> [rviz2-1] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
> [rviz2-1] at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
> [INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 29460]
> [INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 29462]
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353271.176152493] [rviz2.RDFLoader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00404517 seconds
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353271.176198601] [rviz2.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353271.176211876] [rviz2.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
> [rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1710353274.479695119] [rviz2.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353274.512168557] [rviz2.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353274.569129278] [rviz2.RDFLoader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00339469 seconds
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353274.569187604] [rviz2.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353274.569195104] [rviz2.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
> [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710353274.688392692] [rviz2.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> [rviz2-1] malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
> [ERROR] [rviz2-1]: process has died [pid 29448, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/rviz2/rviz2 -d /home/jake/ws_moveit/install/moveit2_tutorials/share/moveit2_tutorials/launch/kinova_moveit_config_demo.rviz --ros-args -r __node:=rviz2 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_3gp4h4ru --params-file /tmp/launch_params_yf08k9sp --params-file /tmp/launch_params_rexkmkx2 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_gvv5k1nd --params-file /tmp/launch_params_50z88v97'].

[re-opening rviz in another terminal by copying the failed command]

> ~$ /opt/ros/humble/lib/rviz2/rviz2 -d /home/jake/ws_moveit/install/moveit2_tutorials/share/moveit2_tutorials/launch/kinova_moveit_config_demo.rviz --ros-args -r __node:=rviz2 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_zvqp4djf --params-file /tmp/launch_params_6mafmodg --params-file /tmp/launch_params_wp9kk605 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_e0rrm3pp --params-file /tmp/launch_params_ojrrr3n1
> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
> 2024-03-19 15:04:33.224 [RTPS_TRANSPORT_SHM Error] Failed init_port fastrtps_port7419: open_and_lock_file failed -> Function open_port_internal
> [INFO] [1710885873.440879568] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
> [INFO] [1710885873.441000848] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
> [INFO] [1710885873.457910955] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
> Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
> at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
> [INFO] [1710885873.762579888] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00221443 seconds
> [INFO] [1710885873.762623689] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
> [INFO] [1710885873.762635502] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
> [ERROR] [1710885877.067277905] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
> [INFO] [1710885877.104106015] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
> [INFO] [1710885877.165162052] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00149257 seconds
> [INFO] [1710885877.165219429] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
> [INFO] [1710885877.165259758] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
> [INFO] [1710885877.535754437] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
> [INFO] [1710885877.536078152] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
> [INFO] [1710885877.540744370] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
> [INFO] [1710885877.541021369] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
> [INFO] [1710885877.550704306] [interactive_marker_display_108082219662592]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
> [INFO] [1710885877.556399553] [moveit_ros_robot_interaction.robot_interaction]: No active joints or end effectors found for group 'gripper'. Make sure that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
> [INFO] [1710885877.557223212] [moveit_ros_robot_interaction.robot_interaction]: No active joints or end effectors found for group 'gripper'. Make sure that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
> [INFO] [1710885877.569453373] [interactive_marker_display_108082219662592]: Sending request for interactive markers
> [INFO] [1710885877.599711641] [interactive_marker_display_108082219662592]: Service response received for initialization
> [INFO] [1710885882.540783118] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
> [INFO] [1710885882.559926196] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
> [INFO] [1710885882.560067730] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group gripper
> [INFO] [1710885882.560102654] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'gripper' in namespace ''

[This time RViz stay active and actually shows the robot.]

Still got the namespace warning. I tried `locate interactive_markers` and got the following output:

> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers/exceptions.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_client.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_server.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers/menu_handler.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers/message_context.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers/tools.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/interactive_markers/interactive_markers/visibility_control.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/rviz_default_plugins/rviz_default_plugins/displays/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/include/rviz_default_plugins/rviz_default_plugins/displays/interactive_markers/integer_action.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/rviz_default_plugins/rviz_default_plugins/displays/interactive_markers/interactive_marker.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/rviz_default_plugins/rviz_default_plugins/displays/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_control.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/rviz_default_plugins/rviz_default_plugins/displays/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_display.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/rviz_default_plugins/rviz_default_plugins/displays/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_namespace_property.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/get_interactive_markers.h
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/get_interactive_markers.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__builder.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__functions.c
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__functions.h
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.h
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c.h
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__struct.h
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__struct.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__traits.hpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__type_support.c
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__type_support.cpp
> /opt/ros/humble/include/visualization_msgs/visualization_msgs/srv/detail/get_interactive_markers__type_support.h
> /opt/ros/humble/lib/libinteractive_markers.so
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers-2.3.2-py3.10.egg-info
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers/**init**.py
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_server.py
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers/menu_handler.py
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers-2.3.2-py3.10.egg-info/PKG-INFO
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers-2.3.2-py3.10.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers-2.3.2-py3.10.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/interactive_markers-2.3.2-py3.10.egg-info/top_level.txt
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/visualization_msgs/srv/_get_interactive_markers.py
> /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/visualization_msgs/srv/_get_interactive_markers_s.c
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_index/resource_index/package_run_dependencies/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_index/resource_index/parent_prefix_path/interactive_markers
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/cmake
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/environment
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/local_setup.bash
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/local_setup.dsv
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/local_setup.sh
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/local_setup.zsh
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/package.dsv
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/package.xml
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/cmake/ament_cmake_export_targets-extras.cmake
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/cmake/export_interactive_markersExport-none.cmake
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/cmake/export_interactive_markersExport.cmake
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/cmake/interactive_markersConfig-version.cmake
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/cmake/interactive_markersConfig.cmake
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/environment/ament_prefix_path.dsv
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/environment/ament_prefix_path.sh
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/environment/path.dsv
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/environment/path.sh
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/environment/pythonpath.dsv
> /opt/ros/humble/share/interactive_markers/environment/pythonpath.sh

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Jake. How did you build rviz and how are you starting it? You have a big warning in your logs you don't address: `SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay`. I would expect something like `cd ~/ws_rviz2 && source ./devel/setup.bash && ros2 run rviz2 rviz2` or wherever you've built rviz2 if not `~/ws_rviz2`. It seems like you have duplicate copies of your rviz installed somehow and that may be how you're getting collisions on the plugins?

Comment: Please *edit your question* to explain where you built rviz and how you're sourcing the built plugins before starting rviz.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Chuck I think you are asking where my source files for RViz are located? If that is what you are asking, I have edited my question to say that I built RViz from my /opt/ros/humble directory (the default location from following the ros2 setup tutorial) and that the plugins are in home/jake/ws_moveit/build directory.

Comment: Ok, working through your first comment. I'll post back in a bit. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Chuck Ok, I tried "locate interactive_markers" and I can't tell if there are namespace clashes (output added to the question). Does that give you any useful info? Thanks again for helping me trouble shoot.

Comment: I have made progress, so I am going to share what I did. But it still feels like there is something fishy going on.

Comment: Well, the progress was only that I could now vizualize the robot arm in the reopened rviz. Still puzzling over this namespace issue as it seems to be getting in the way of the next steps in the tutorial (specifically interacting with the robot arm - seem like dhood had a namespace related issue as well: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/49165/moveit-rviz-plugin-no-interactive-markers-visible-available)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I never figured out exactly why I was getting a namespace issue. But I deleted my .cache, .ros, .rviz, and ws_moveit2 folders and went through the build process again and now things are working. I think maybe what happened what I tried to install Moveit following this page:
https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/source/

and then went on to the getting started tutorial:
https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html

which basically has you reinstall moveit. That makes the most sense to me as far as why I might be getting a weird namespace issue. (I did end up deleting the ws_moveit2 folder before I even got to the namespace issue. Maybe just deleting the .cache folder would have been enough? Who knows.)

Note: still looks like I am getting a namespace collision warning, but the tutorial works fine now. So I guess namespace collision wasn't the root issue...?

Thanks again Chuck for taking some time to help me investigate.